# Problem merging cells - IEEEtran class

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I have a problem when I want to merge two cells in a table, with the `IEEEtran` class. Usually, the `multicolumn` works perfectly, but, with this class, the text that is supposed to be in the merged cell is present twice, as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

The code I used is:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering 
\caption{My caption} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Cell A & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cell B} \\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline 
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I tried different options (`\usepackage{multirow}`, etc.) but it does not work.

Would you have any clue?

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). // Please make your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: With your code snippet, as I expected, I can't reproduce your problem. Please provide small complete document, which double text in `multicolumn` cell.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
It's actually part of a project where I used an example template in ShareLatex using the \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}.
Many packages were already called at the beginning of the document, including \usepackage{mdwtab} that may be the source of the problem, but I don't know what is it for.

Comment: @G.Leboucher, please test `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{mdwtab}\begin{document}\begin{table}\centering  \caption{My caption} \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline  Cell A & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cell B} \\ \hline   1  & 2   & 3  \\ \hline
    4  & 5  & 6  \\ \hline \end{tabular} \end{table}
\end{document}`.  For sure `mdwtab` is not source of your problem. I deeply doubt that this error is result of your code snippet.  Unfortunately my crystal ball is broken, so I cant see your document in it and what you really doing in it :-(

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code in pdfLaTeX, I get the following output:

[image]